# Not able to send message to Solace JMS Queue

Tags: java, jms, jms-topic, solace-mq, solace

I need to push message to Solace JMS queue Webpshere but I am getting below error during send message. I have also increase message listener size but not solved problem.

```
Error:
503: Spool Over Quota. Message VPN limit exceeded

Caused by: com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPErrorResponseException: 503: Spool Over Quota. Message VPN limit exceeded - Topic '#P2P/QUE/testqueue' [Subcode:30]
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.JCSMPXMLMessageProducer.getAndProcessResponse(JCSMPXMLMessageProducer.java:1001)
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.JCSMPXMLMessageProducer.handlePubMsgResponse(JCSMPXMLMessageProducer.java:1621)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a configuration problem on your listener side; Solace queues can have several size limits applied, and one of them tripped here.

- there can be a limit for the entire message VPN, which will override any queue specific size limits.
- there can be a configured limit on the queue itself (testqueue) which is hit.

To reduce the spool usage on the appliance, you'll have to consume and ack messages from the queues in this VPN or use a queue browser to delete messages directly.